# Select a value where another column has the highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with people, their age, and their awesomeness at each age.

What is the simplest query to get John's 'awesomeness' at their maximum age?

People

```
Name    Age    Awesomeness
Don    1      12
Don    2      23
Don    3      43
Don    4      30
Sam     1      9
Sam     2      18
Sam     3      59
Sam     4      99
```

The best query I have:

```
SELECT awesomeness
FROM people
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(age)
  FROM people
  WHERE name = 'Don'
) a 
ON people.age = a.age
WHERE people.name = 'Don'
```

Comment: What should happen if there are two rows with the same name and age?

Comment: return both please :)

Comment: In that case, the query you have does the trick.

Comment: actually returning 1 is ok. Sorry to change the question on you cdhowie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT awesomeness
FROM people
WHERE people.name = 'Don' 
ORDER BY age desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I had this thought too, but see OP's comment on their question. :(

Comment: actually returning 1 is fine, sorry about that cdhowie!

Answer (score 0):

You may be wishing to show everyone's score at their maximum age.

You can do that with this query:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0ff4/1/0

```
SELECT a.name, a.awesomeness
  FROM people a
  JOIN (
         SELECT name, MAX(age) age
           FROM people
          GROUP by name
       ) b ON a.name = b.name AND a.age=b.age
```

Comment: Thanks Ollie - in this case just looking for one person's